# How to print in a Separate Line when using 3 Loops

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

In Java:

```
public class Looping {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for(int a=1;a<=10;a++){
           System.out.println (a); // 
        }
        for(int a=1;a<=10;a++){
            System.out.print (a); // print without spaces
        }
        // I need to know what code should go here to start the next loop in a new line
        for(int a=1;a<=10;a++){
            System.out.print (a+ " ");//print with spaces
        }
    }
}
```

The result is

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
123456789101 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

I want to know how to take the 3rd loop to a new line. Like below

```
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 6
 7
 8
 9
 10
 12345678910
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just add  System.out.println(); after the second loop ?

Comment: Both above lines do the task :) Thank you :*

Answer (score 1):

Just add an empty println between the loops

```
System.out.println ("");
```

Answer (score 1):

add System.out.println (""); between the loops. it should work.